# Why are questions on naming conventions considered to be opinion based?

Tags: discussion

Specifically in the case where the language publisher has published guidelines on the matter?

For example, Microsoft have published MSDN pages recommending naming and casing conventions for CLR languages. Sure, you *could* use any naming and casing convention you like (which is the opinion part), but there *is* a published recommended style guide (the existence of which is not opinion based), that I would consider to consist of canonical recommendations.

Comment: Did you specifically ask for the MSDN published convention in your question?

Comment: @BSMP No, he didn't, he asked why a particular snippet deviated from the established convention.

Comment: I guess that all depends on if you prefer spaces or tabs. Or both... it better not be both though.

Comment: @TravisJ Clearly the solution is to never have any whitespace in your code at all.  Then there's no ambiguity in how the IDE should render the code.

Comment: @BSMP No, I asked if there was a reason and gave snippets of code from Microsoft, eg `get_Item()`, But I ask moreso for future reference rather than for justification of my feeling slighted for receiving close votes :-)

Comment: `the suggested one is AFAIK entirely about generic choices - which is what Ive specifically said I wasnt asking about` Your meta question included no such information.  In my case I saw your actual question, and so knew what your actual question asked, but as you didn't include such details in your meta question they can't know that.

Comment: The framework design guidelines are *guidelines*, and they do have a bit of wiggle room in them.  They're also published online and are pretty accessible, so what was stopping you from answering your own question?

Comment: Because unless you're asking about a specific convention, all you're doing is starting a flame war.  There is no technical reason to prefer one style to another, so its off topic here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your question wasn't asking what Microsoft's recommendations for a particular naming convention should be.  (Which is itself just asking for a particular group's opinion on a matter.)  Your question was asking why a particular code snippet used a naming convention that it did.  Nobody can tell you that but the person that wrote it.  Anyone else can only ever guess at why, which is an opinion.

Comment: I gave reffered to that question purely to show where I was coming from, but I do not ask "Why was my question closed", which, no offense, is what you seem to be answering. I still am unsure if it is OK to ask such questions in the specific case I describe... maybe you are saying that it would be _if_ I had mentioned that??

Comment: @Toby You *didn't* describe any situation.  You just named a broad topic, "naming conventions", and there's no way to speak about every single possible question related to that topic as a whole.

Comment: `"_Specifically_ in the case where..."` Is that not describing a situation? If not then I am confused. Yes you saw my closed question. I am not asking about that one. I am asking, for future reference, for the situation described in _this_ question.

Comment: I will edit my question to be more clear

Comment: @Toby That doesn't describe a question, or even a type of question.  You could ask any type of question when discussing a topic that is in that situation.